Establishing a side length in Morley's Trisector Theorem
This diagram represents a triangle in which each angle is trisected so that $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=60^{\circ}$

With a little effort, we can prove $\triangle{KLM}$ is equilateral, which I did by establishing the following set of cyclic relationships:
$|AL|=8R \sin{\gamma}\sin{\beta}\sin{(60+\beta)}$
$|AM|=8R \sin{\beta}\sin{\gamma}\sin{(60+\gamma)}$
$\alpha'=60+\beta$
$\alpha''=60+\gamma$
To obtain the length |ML|, it seems natural to use the law of sines:
$\frac{|ML|}{|AL|}=\frac{\sin{\alpha}}{\sin{\alpha'}}=\frac{\sin{\alpha}}{\sin{60+\beta}} \Rightarrow |ML|=|AL|\frac{\sin{\alpha}}{\sin{60+\beta}}= 8R \sin{\gamma}\sin{\beta}\sin{\alpha}$
However, I have seen authors imply that $|ML|$ is also easy to obtain via the law of cosines, i.e.:
$|ML|^2=|AM|^2+|AL|^2-2|AM||AL|\cos{\alpha}$
$|ML|^2=8^2R^2\sin^2{\gamma}\sin^2{\beta}\Big[\sin^2{(60+\gamma)}+\sin^2{(60+\beta)}-2\sin{(60+\gamma)}\sin{(60+\beta)}\cos{\alpha}\Big]$
From the derivation of $|ML|$ above, we must have:
$\sin^2{\alpha}=\Big[\sin^2{(60+\gamma)}+\sin^2{(60+\beta)}-2\sin{(60+\gamma)}\sin{(60+\beta)}\cos{\alpha}\Big]$
But this equivalence is not obvious to me, nor have my manipulations shown the equivalence.
Question: Is the equivalence obvious? How can it be (quickly) established?

Connected : this document

Thanks @JeanMarie, I scanned it and will take a closer look. The thing is that the notes I was looking at made it seem like it was so obvious that the side length followed from the facts I listed paired with the cosine rule that I feel I’m overlooking some obvious trig identity or something like that.

@RobinSparrow Mathematica does indeed simplify the formula in square brackets to an expression equivalent to $\sin^2\alpha$ (not $\sin\alpha$, you should correct) but it isn't an obvious equality, in my opinion.

Lets define:
$$
b=60°+\beta,\quad c=60°+\gamma,
\quad\text{so that:}\quad
\alpha=60°-\beta-\gamma=180°-b-c.
$$
Your expression can then be written as:
$$
\begin{align}
&\sin^2c+\sin^2b+2\sin b\sin c\cos(b+c)\\
=\ &\sin^2c+\sin^2b+2\sin b\sin c\ (\cos b\cos c-\sin b \sin c)\\
=\ &\sin^2c+\sin^2b-2\sin^2b\sin^2c+2\sin b\cos b\sin c\cos c\\
=\ &\sin^2c(1-\sin^2b)+\sin^2b(1-\sin^2c)+2\sin b\cos b\sin c\cos c\\
=\ &\sin^2c\cos^2b+\sin^2b\cos^2c+2\sin b\cos b\sin c\cos c\\
=\ &(\sin c\cos b+\sin b\cos c)^2\\
=\ &\sin^2(c+b)\\
=\ &\sin^2(180°-\alpha)\\
=\ &\sin^2\alpha\\
\end{align}
$$

The term split in line 3 to 4 is what I missed, this is great, thanks!
